# Complex Joins on tables in SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, join

My question is about joining these tables in queries.We have 4 tables called prsn having prsn details,then ***prsn_rltn having beneficiary's id but the details of that beneficiary will be present in prsn table only, that is PRSN_ID will have both person id as well as beneficiary id***,then we have a table called payment and then a table called payment form.The below are the columns in each table.

```
**PRSN**:
PRSN_ID EMPLOYEE_ID NAME    BRTH_DT
**PRSN_RLTN**:
PRIM_PRSN_ID   SCND_PRSN_ID
**PAYMENT**:
PRSN_ID   PMT_ID   PMT_BEGIN_DATE
**PAYMENT FORM**:
PRSN_ID   PMT_FORM_ID
```

The quetion is that we have to get persons having a paticular pmt_id(ex:1000) and pmt_begin_date(ex:01/01/2014).His employee_id,name and brth_dt should be displayed along with his beneficiary's id,name and brth_dt.                                                     I have written a code to display all the other details except the beneficiary's details. So please do take a look at the query below and let me know how to display beneficiary's details.

```
SELECT
,A.PRSN_ID
,A.EMPLOYEE_ID
,A.NAME
,A.BRTH_DT
,B.PMT_ID
,B.PMT_BEGIN_DATE
,C.PMT_FORM_ID

FROM
&DATABASE.PRSN AS A

LEFT JOIN  &DATABASE.PAYMENT_FORM AS C
ON A.PRSN_ID = C.PRSN_ID
AND C.PMT_FORM_ID=200       

&DATABASE.PAYMENT AS B

WHERE
B.PMT_ID = 1000
AND B.PMT_BEGIN_DATE='01/01/2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is syntactically wrong. You need a `JOIN` for each table, try the following query and see if it helps. Also `LEFT JOIN` and `JOIN` are not the same, so please read up on them before you use any of them.

```
SELECT
    A.PRSN_ID
    ,A.EMPLOYEE_ID
    ,A.NAME
    ,A.BRTH_DT
    ,B.PMT_ID
    ,B.PMT_BEGIN_DATE
    ,C.PMT_FORM_ID
    ,B.PRSN_ID
    ,B.EMPLOYEE_ID
    ,B.NAME
FROM &DATABASE.PRSN AS A
    LEFT JOIN  &DATABASE.PAYMENT_FORM AS C
    ON A.PRSN_ID = C.PRSN_ID
    AND C.PMT_FORM_ID=200
    LEFT JOIN &DATABASE.PAYMENT AS P ON C.PMT_FORM_ID = P.PMT_ID
    LEFT JOIN PRSN_RLTN R ON R.PRIM_PRSN_ID = A.PRSN_ID
    LEFT JOIN &DATABASE.PRSN AS B ON B.PRSN_ID = R.SCND_PRSN_ID
WHERE
    B.PMT_ID = 1000
    AND B.PMT_BEGIN_DATE='01/01/2014'
```

Comment: You forgot to join the `PRSN_RLTN` table to get the beneficiary ID.

Comment: I asked as OP highlighted that above; you could always make an assumption.

Comment: @Price Thanks, I will modify my answer to incorporate that into the query.

Comment: I see. Why would you join on `C.PMT_FORM_ID = P.PMT_ID`? Both are different values.

Comment: The OPs post doesn't have any info about how a payment is related to a payee. So I thought these values may be the same.